# Spacing between Divs - margin-bottom not working

Tags: css, html

This question has been asked, yet the answers aren't working for me.  I've tried to change Div padding, and Margin-Bottom on the Divs.

I would like to decrease the space between these three divs:

[image]

```css
.center-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.title_top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='center-div' style="background-color:lightgrey">
  <div class="title_top" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-user">
         </i> Total Users
  </div>
  <div class="title_center" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>2500</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="title_bottom" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: #009900;">
          </i>
    <i> 4%</i> From last Week
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you try to give negative value to margin-bottoms? `margin-bottom: -10px` fe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<h1>` element has a default margin you can eliminate:

```css
.center-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.title_top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='center-div' style="background-color:lightgrey">
  <div class="title_top" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-user">
         </i> Total Users
  </div>
  <div class="title_center" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>2500</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="title_bottom" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: #009900;">
          </i>
    <i> 4%</i> From last Week
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so very much!!  I can't accept your answer for another 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the `margin` for your `h1` tag.
See added style classes `margin-5` or `no-margin`

```css
.center-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.title_top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.margin-5 { margin: 5px !important; }
.no-margin { margin: 0px !important; }
```

```html
<div class='center-div' style="background-color:lightgrey">
  <div class="title_top" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-user">
         </i> Total Users
  </div>
  <div class="title_center" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 class="margin-5">2500</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="title_bottom" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: #009900;">
          </i>
    <i> 4%</i> From last Week
  </div>
</div>

<div class='center-div' style="background-color:lightgrey; margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="title_top" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-user">
         </i> Total Users
  </div>
  <div class="title_center" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 class="no-margin">2500</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="title_bottom" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: #009900;">
          </i>
    <i> 4%</i> From last Week
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks daan.  j08691's answer worked for me.  Thanks for responding though.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `h1` `line-height`

```css
.center-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.title_top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* float:left;  remove */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.center-div h1 {
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 0.1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='center-div' style="background-color:lightgrey">
  <div class="title_top" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-user">
         </i> Total Users
  </div>
  <div class="title_center" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>2500</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="title_bottom" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: #009900;">
          </i>
    <i> 4%</i> From last Week
  </div>
</div>
```